# Creating database for inquiries

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a database for inquiries, such that I will take the inquiry as an input and the output will be an appropriate reply. You can think about it as if it is a questions & answers database.

The followings are samples similar to three of my tables:

**phrases table**

```
Phrase

id      phrase
-------------------
1       what
2       what is
3       what is the
```

**inquiries table**

```
Inquiry

id      inquiry
------------------------
1       highest mountain
```

**replies table**

```
Reply

phrase_id   inquiry_id      reply
-----------------------------------------
3           1               mount everest
```

Let the input be:  " *What is the highest mountain ?* "

Can I make a query such that it knows that "what is the" is phrase and "highest mountain" is inquiry, and shows the reply as an output ?

Comment: Google it. Simple database association. Read the manual.

Comment: [Read this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)

Comment: I liked the tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: tutsplus is a very good site for learning new things, try and explore it when there's new things you want to learn. :)

Comment: @Martin  Sure, I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create such query by joining your 3 tables, and searching for the question in the concatenated phrase + inquiry (although I doubt that this would be the most efficient way of creating such a database, but this is way beyond the scope of SO and this topic).

```
select reply
from replies r
inner join phrases p on r.phrase_id=p.id
inner join inquiries i on r.inquiry_id=i.id
where concat(p.phrase, ' ', i.inquiry)=lower('searched expression')
```

'searched expression' is the input parameter.

Comment: Just noticed you'd posted a very similar answer. The only (minor) difference I can find is that i added a wildcard into the concatenation. The aim of this was to trim additional characters (such as the question mark etc)

Answer (score 1):

This is the working version I came up with:

```
SELECT r.reply FROM Reply r LEFT JOIN Phrase p ON r.phrase_id=p.id LEFT JOIN Inquiry i ON r.inquiry_id=i.id WHERE LOWER('What is the highest mountain ?') LIKE LOWER(CONCAT(p.phrase, ' ', i.inquiry, '%'))
```